# SQL Query join with a count and avg from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Actually the math doesn't seem to be adding up.

Here is the query I'm using and the 2 table's i'm trying to access (with all real data).

This query in SQL is pulling `Steve Smith` to have 27 sum and 27 count of `amount`. It should be 17. In the same query it is showing `John Smith` to have 4 sum and 2 count of `amount`.

```
SELECT
user.*,
IFNULL(SUM(collection.amount), 0) AS usertotal,
COUNT(collection.amount) AS userunique
FROM user
LEFT JOIN collection
ON user.id = collection.userid
GROUP BY collection.amount`
```

Table 1 (named `user`):

```
id | firstname | lastname | username | email
1  | Steve     | Smith    | SteveS   | Steve@Smith.com
2  | John      | Smith    | JohnSmith| John@Smith.com
```

Table 2 (named `collection`):

```
id|userid|carid |amount
1   1   74  1
10  2   130 1
11  2   48  1
12  2   414 1
13  2   415 1
14  2   66  1
15  2   404 1
16  2   57  2
17  2   331 1
18  2   264 1
19  2   325 1
20  2   51  2
21  2   185 1
24  1   168 1
25  1   11  1
26  1   315 1
27  1   51  1
28  1   210 1
29  1   433 1
30  1   434 1
31  1   460 1
32  1   75  1
33  1   238 1
34  1   226 1
35  1   396 1
36  1   174 1
37  1   12  1
38  1   328 1
39  1   4   1



id| UN | Amount
1 | 4  | 457
2 | 4  | 28
3 | 2  | 234
4 | 1  | 235
5 | 2  | 1
```

I need a query to get the entire list of names of users, and inner join (with sum and count on the amount column) between user.id and collection.UN

I don't know the SQL query, can't figure it out for the life of me. Help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  user.UN as username, 
  IFNULL(SUM(collection.Amount), 0) AS sum,
  COUNT(collection.Amount) AS count
FROM user
LEFT JOIN collection
  ON user.id = collection.UN
GROUP BY user.id
```

You said you wanted to use `INNER JOIN`, but that won't display those users who doesn't have a record in the collection table. So instead I used `LEFT JOIN` so that the entire list of users will be returned, and the `COUNT` and `SUM` of their amounts will be 0 if they doesn't have any.

Comment: The math actually doesn't add up. I'll update my original post and explain.

Comment: Is the `SUM` just working fine? And for the problem with `COUNT`, I guess it's because it also counts the null values. I'll work on a fix now.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Ah I now get it. The problem is with your `GROUP BY` statement. It should be `GROUP BY user.id` rather than `collection.amount`. Try it again :)

Comment: That was it! I guess I don't understand GROUP BY, I need to look into that this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    select u.* , c.total_amount from users as u 
inner join (select un, sum(amount) total_amount 
from collection group by un)  c on u.id = c.un
```

PHP Query:

```
 $q = "select u.* , c.total_amount from users as u 
inner join (select un, sum(amount) total_amount 
from collection group by un)  c on u.id = c.un";    
    $result = $this->db->query($q);
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: I think it should read "on user.id=collection.UN" instead of "user.id=collection.id".

Comment: It should I believe, but even when I change that with the above code I get: `Unknown column 'c.userid' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @veekay used aliases in the query. Ok do one thing just replace u with users(table 1 name) and c with collection(table 2 name) and check the result.

Comment: It's working on my local. @Andrew Try to adjust according to your requirement.